# Entity Group Join without calling all columns in tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm having an issue pulling only the columns specified in the query when I introduce a GroupJoin. For simplicity, I've narrowed the code down to just the issue, but there are many other joins. Due to the complexity of the full statement, I would very much prefer not to have to Union where != null to == null, having to write basically identical code over and over...

With a standard join:

```
var ret = await _ICMDbContext.CaseHeader
                .Join(_ICMDbContext.Employee, ch => ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey, emp => emp.IdRec, (ch, emp) => new { ch, emp })
                .Where(x=> x.ch.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
                .Select(x => new CaseHeaderGridModel()
                {
                    IdRec = x.ch.IdRec,
                    CaseCategoryId = x.ch.CaseCategoryId,
                    CreateDttm = x.ch.CreateDttm,
                    CreateUser = x.ch.CreateUser,
                    EmployeeIdRecFkey = x.ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey,
                    EmployeeName = x.ch.EmployeeName,
                    EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey = x.ch.EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey,
                    CaseEmployerName = x.ch.EmployerName,
                    OccurrenceTreatmentState = x.ch.EventState,
                    CallItemAssignedUserObjectId = x.ch.CallItemAssignedUserObjectId,
                    CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId = x.ch.CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId.Value,
                    CaseItemLocator = x.ch.CaseItemLocator,
                    CaseStatusId = x.ch.CaseStatusId,
                    RequiredLanguageId = x.ch.RequiredLanguageId,
                    NameFirst = x.emp.NameFirst,
                    NameMiddle = x.emp.NameMiddle,
                    NameLast = x.emp.NameLast
                })                                    
                .ToListAsync();
```

The expected SQL with requested columns only, is generated:

```
SELECT [ch].[IdRec], [ch].[CaseCategoryId], [ch].[CreateDttm], [ch].[CreateUser], [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey], [ch].[EmployeeName]
, [ch].[EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey], [ch].[EmployerName] AS [CaseEmployerName], [ch].[EventState] AS [OccurrenceTreatmentState]
, [ch].[CallItemAssignedUserObjectId], [ch].[CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId], [ch].[CaseItemLocator], [ch].[CaseStatusId]
, [ch].[RequiredLanguageId], [emp].[NameFirst], [emp].[NameMiddle], [emp].[NameLast]
FROM [CaseHeader] AS [ch]
INNER JOIN [Employee] AS [emp] ON [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey] = [emp].[IdRec]
WHERE [ch].[IsDeleted] = 0
```

However, when I turn this into a GroupJoin (There may not be a linked employee, need a Left):

```
var ret = await _ICMDbContext.CaseHeader
.GroupJoin(_ICMDbContext.Employee, ch => ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey, emp => emp.IdRec, (ch, emp) => new { ch, emp = emp.FirstOrDefault() })
.Where(x=> x.ch.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
.Select(x => new CaseHeaderGridModel()
{
    IdRec = x.ch.IdRec,
    CaseCategoryId = x.ch.CaseCategoryId,
    CreateDttm = x.ch.CreateDttm,
    CreateUser = x.ch.CreateUser,
    EmployeeIdRecFkey = x.ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey,
    EmployeeName = x.ch.EmployeeName,
    EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey = x.ch.EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey,
    CaseEmployerName = x.ch.EmployerName,
    OccurrenceTreatmentState = x.ch.EventState,
    CallItemAssignedUserObjectId = x.ch.CallItemAssignedUserObjectId,
    CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId = x.ch.CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId.Value,
    CaseItemLocator = x.ch.CaseItemLocator,
    CaseStatusId = x.ch.CaseStatusId,
    RequiredLanguageId = x.ch.RequiredLanguageId,
    NameFirst = x.emp.NameFirst,
    NameMiddle = x.emp.NameMiddle,
    NameLast = x.emp.NameLast
})                                    
.ToListAsync();
```

I get every column from both tables (all tables in reality)

```
SELECT [ch].[IdRec] AS [IdRec0], [ch].[AdditionalData], [ch].[BillToClientOrgIdRecFkey], [ch].[CallGroupLocator], [ch].[CallItemAssignedUserObjectId]
, [ch].[CallItemLocator], [ch].[CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId], [ch].[CallItemTypeId], [ch].[CallerName], [ch].[CallerOrganization], [ch].[CaseCategoryId]
, [ch].[CaseItemContacts], [ch].[CaseItemLocator], [ch].[CaseOutcomeWithIntervention_OutcomeId], [ch].[CaseOutcomeWithoutIntervention_OutcomeId]
, [ch].[CaseStatusId], [ch].[CaseWorkflowPhaseId], [ch].[ChangeData], [ch].[CreateDttm] AS [CreateDttm0], [ch].[CreateUser] AS [CreateUser0]
, [ch].[CurrentMedicalStatusCalc], [ch].[DateOfBirth], [ch].[EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey], [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey], [ch].[EmployeeName]
, [ch].[EmployeePhoneNumber], [ch].[EmployerName] AS [CaseEmployerName], [ch].[EventCity], [ch].[EventDateTime], [ch].[EventDateTimeQualifierId]
, [ch].[EventDescription], [ch].[EventElevatedAdvice], [ch].[EventGeographicDescription], [ch].[EventState] AS [OccurrenceTreatmentState], [ch].[GenderId]
, [ch].[GeneratedFromVoicemail], [ch].[HandednessId], [ch].[IsDeleted], [ch].[JobDutiesDescription], [ch].[JobPhysicalityClassificationId]
, [ch].[LocalClientOrgId], [ch].[LocaleId], [ch].[MedicalHistory], [ch].[NoteData], [ch].[PhoneCallerIdExt], [ch].[PhoneCallerIdNumber]
, [ch].[PhoneStatedCallBackExt], [ch].[PhoneStatedCallBackNumber], [ch].[RequiredLanguageId], [ch].[ServiceCategoryId], [ch].[ServiceOrgNotifiedDispositionId]
, [ch].[SysRowVersion], [ch].[SysTag], [ch].[ThirdPartyEmployer], [ch].[ThirdPartyEmployerIdRecFkey], [ch].[TimezoneId], [ch].[TreatmentCity]
, [ch].[TreatmentState], [ch].[UpdateDttm], [ch].[UpdateUser], [ch].[WorkDaysCalcLostTime], [ch].[WorkDaysCalcRestricted], [ch].[WorkScheduleDescription]
, [ch].[WorkdayDateEstimatedReturn], [ch].[WorkdayDateFirstMissed], [ch].[WorkdayDateFullReturn], [ch].[WorkdayDateRestrictedReturn], [ch].[WorkloadMetricValue]
, [emp].[IdRec], [emp].[AdditionalData], [emp].[ClientEmployeeIdentity], [emp].[CostCenter], [emp].[CreateDttm], [emp].[CreateUser], [emp].[DateOfBirth]
, [emp].[DispositionId], [emp].[EmploymentEndDate], [emp].[EmploymentStartDate], [emp].[ExternalReferenceEmployeeId], [emp].[ExternalReferenceEmployeeId_Source]
, [emp].[GenderId], [emp].[HandednessId], [emp].[IdRecParent], [emp].[IsDeleted], [emp].[JobPhysicalityClassificationId], [emp].[JobTitleId], [emp].[LanguageId]
, [emp].[LocalClientOrgId], [emp].[NameFirst], [emp].[NameFirstPreferred], [emp].[NameGenerationalTitleId], [emp].[NameLast], [emp].[NameMiddle]
, [emp].[NameProfessionalTitle], [emp].[NameTitleId], [emp].[NationalOrStateIdNumber], [emp].[PersonnelLocatorCode], [emp].[SysRowVersion], [emp].[SysTag]
, [emp].[ThirdPartyEmployerName], [emp].[ThirdPartyEmployerNameIdRecFkey], [emp].[UpdateDttm], [emp].[UpdateUser], [emp].[WorkerClassificationId]
FROM [CaseHeader] AS [ch]
LEFT JOIN [Employee] AS [emp] ON [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey] = [emp].[IdRec]
WHERE [ch].[IsDeleted] = 0
ORDER BY [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey]
```

As stated above, this is actually a much more complex query, and there are multiple GroupJoins in it - the actual number of columns pulling back when using GroupJoins is in the hundreds, and our dataset is fairly large, so this is causing our query to take upwards of 15-20 seconds to return, whereas if I limit columns to only what I'm requesting, it returns in less than a second.

Is there a way to get past this with GroupJoin (or another way to get a Left Join), or do I need to Union and create a bunch of branches?

Selecting a CaseHeaderModel from the context, and then performing the GroupJoin on the Model instead of the context does not change the generated SQL. GroupJoin just really seems to want to grab all columns.

**Edit**
I've tried the below code, and unfortunately it still pulls in all columns:

```
var ret = _ICMDbContext.CaseHeader
                .GroupJoin(_ICMDbContext.Employee, ch => ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey, emp => emp.IdRec, (ch, emp) => new
                {
                    ch = new
                    {
                        ch.IdRec,
                        ch.CaseCategoryId,
                        ch.CaseStatusId,
                        ch.IsDeleted,
                        ch.CreateDttm,
                        ch.CreateUser,
                        ch.CallItemTypeId,
                        ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey,
                        ch.EmployeeName,
                        ch.EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey,
                        ch.EmployerName,
                        ch.EventState,
                        ch.CallItemAssignedUserObjectId,
                        ch.CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId,
                        ch.CaseItemLocator,
                        ch.RequiredLanguageId
                    }
                ,
                    emp = emp.Select(x => new
                    {
                        x.NameFirst,
                        x.NameMiddle,
                        x.NameLast
                    }).FirstOrDefault()
                })                    
                .Where(x=> x.ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey != null && x.ch.IsDeleted.Equals(false))
                .Select(x => new CaseHeaderGridModel()
                {
                    IdRec = x.ch.IdRec,
                    CaseCategoryId = x.ch.CaseCategoryId,
                    CreateDttm = TimeZoneConverter.GetConvertFromDateToDate(x.ch.CreateDttm, utcAdditionalData, loggedInUserTimeZoneAddlData).Value,
                    CreateDttmValue = TimeZoneConverter.GetConvertFromDateToDateFormattedTimeString(x.ch.CreateDttm, utcAdditionalData, loggedInUserTimeZoneAddlData),
                    CreateTimezoneShortName = TimeZoneConverter.GetTimeZoneShortName(x.ch.CreateDttm, loggedInUserTimeZoneAddlData),
                    CreateUser = x.ch.CreateUser,
                    CallItemTypeId = x.ch.CallItemTypeId.Value,
                    EmployeeIdRecFkey = x.ch.EmployeeIdRecFkey,
                    EmployeeName = x.ch.EmployeeName,
                    EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey = x.ch.EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey,
                    CaseEmployerName = x.ch.EmployerName,
                    OccurrenceTreatmentState = x.ch.EventState,
                    CallItemAssignedUserObjectId = x.ch.CallItemAssignedUserObjectId,
                    CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId = x.ch.CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId.Value,
                    CaseItemLocator = x.ch.CaseItemLocator,                       
                    RequiredLanguageId = x.ch.RequiredLanguageId,
                    NameFirst = x.emp.NameFirst,
                    NameMiddle = x.emp.NameMiddle,
                    NameLast = x.emp.NameLast,
                    CaseStatusId = x.ch.CaseStatusId,
                }).ToList();
```

I get the same:

```
SELECT [ch].[IdRec] AS [IdRec0], [ch].[AdditionalData], [ch].[BillToClientOrgIdRecFkey], [ch].[CallGroupLocator], [ch].[CallItemAssignedUserObjectId]
, [ch].[CallItemLocator], [ch].[CallItemOriginatorUserObjectId], [ch].[CallItemTypeId], [ch].[CallerName], [ch].[CallerOrganization], [ch].[CaseCategoryId]
, [ch].[CaseItemContacts], [ch].[CaseItemLocator], [ch].[CaseOutcomeWithIntervention_OutcomeId], [ch].[CaseOutcomeWithoutIntervention_OutcomeId]
, [ch].[CaseStatusId], [ch].[CaseWorkflowPhaseId], [ch].[ChangeData], [ch].[CreateDttm], [ch].[CreateUser] AS [CreateUser0]
, [ch].[CurrentMedicalStatusCalc], [ch].[DateOfBirth], [ch].[EmployeeClientOrgIdRecFkey], [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey], [ch].[EmployeeName]
, [ch].[EmployeePhoneNumber], [ch].[EmployerName] AS [CaseEmployerName], [ch].[EventCity], [ch].[EventDateTime], [ch].[EventDateTimeQualifierId]
, [ch].[EventDescription], [ch].[EventElevatedAdvice], [ch].[EventGeographicDescription], [ch].[EventState] AS [OccurrenceTreatmentState], [ch].[GenderId]
, [ch].[GeneratedFromVoicemail], [ch].[HandednessId], [ch].[IsDeleted], [ch].[JobDutiesDescription], [ch].[JobPhysicalityClassificationId]
, [ch].[LocalClientOrgId], [ch].[LocaleId], [ch].[MedicalHistory], [ch].[NoteData], [ch].[PhoneCallerIdExt], [ch].[PhoneCallerIdNumber]
, [ch].[PhoneStatedCallBackExt], [ch].[PhoneStatedCallBackNumber], [ch].[RequiredLanguageId], [ch].[ServiceCategoryId]
, [ch].[ServiceOrgNotifiedDispositionId], [ch].[SysRowVersion], [ch].[SysTag], [ch].[ThirdPartyEmployer], [ch].[ThirdPartyEmployerIdRecFkey]
, [ch].[TimezoneId], [ch].[TreatmentCity], [ch].[TreatmentState], [ch].[UpdateDttm], [ch].[UpdateUser], [ch].[WorkDaysCalcLostTime]
, [ch].[WorkDaysCalcRestricted], [ch].[WorkScheduleDescription], [ch].[WorkdayDateEstimatedReturn], [ch].[WorkdayDateFirstMissed]
, [ch].[WorkdayDateFullReturn], [ch].[WorkdayDateRestrictedReturn], [ch].[WorkloadMetricValue], [emp].[IdRec], [emp].[AdditionalData]
, [emp].[ClientEmployeeIdentity], [emp].[CostCenter], [emp].[CreateDttm], [emp].[CreateUser], [emp].[DateOfBirth], [emp].[DispositionId]
, [emp].[EmploymentEndDate], [emp].[EmploymentStartDate], [emp].[ExternalReferenceEmployeeId], [emp].[ExternalReferenceEmployeeId_Source]
, [emp].[GenderId], [emp].[HandednessId], [emp].[IdRecParent], [emp].[IsDeleted], [emp].[JobPhysicalityClassificationId], [emp].[JobTitleId]
, [emp].[LanguageId], [emp].[LocalClientOrgId], [emp].[NameFirst], [emp].[NameFirstPreferred], [emp].[NameGenerationalTitleId], [emp].[NameLast]
, [emp].[NameMiddle], [emp].[NameProfessionalTitle], [emp].[NameTitleId], [emp].[NationalOrStateIdNumber], [emp].[PersonnelLocatorCode]
, [emp].[SysRowVersion], [emp].[SysTag], [emp].[ThirdPartyEmployerName], [emp].[ThirdPartyEmployerNameIdRecFkey], [emp].[UpdateDttm], [emp].[UpdateUser]
, [emp].[WorkerClassificationId]
FROM [CaseHeader] AS [ch]
LEFT JOIN [Employee] AS [emp] ON [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey] = [emp].[IdRec]
WHERE [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey] IS NOT NULL AND ([ch].[IsDeleted] = 0)
ORDER BY [ch].[EmployeeIdRecFkey]
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with not using SelectMany. I didn't realize this was required when I would always have 1 match, and was only using the left join to cover nulls. I thought putting the FirstOrDefault() in the GroupJoin would do basically the same thing. When adding SelectMany, the columns are selected correctly.